# Built-in next method acting strange

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, pcap

[image]

When I use a imported package, I use an object that it gives to me. I found it has a `next` method so I just try use `next()` build-in function to generate next item of it,but something is wrong. And i wonder what is the built-in method of an Object, I never see it before. And i am using python 2.7.12
Thank you!

Comment: You need to have an Iterator object for next to make sense.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to be sure, but I'm guessing the built-in `next()` function isn't recognizing that the `Reader` object `p` is an iterator (probably because it doesn't have an `__iter__()` method), so it doesn't call its `next()` method.

Comment: What is this `Reader` object coming from? It looks like a buggy C implementation that defined a `next` method directly without setting `tp_iternext`.

Comment: Are you using Pcapy?

Comment: Thank you, I am indeed using pcapy. And in my opinion,  the built-in function next don't need an iterator. If an obeject have a next() method it  can be passed to built-in function next. The object needn't to have __iter__().I have test it. I have a object just have next method. I t can be passed to built-in function next.

Comment: Please do not paste pictures of code into your question. Copy-paste the actual code & error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` builtin function is behaving perfectly fine. While `Reader()` does appear to have a `next()` method, it is missing another important method. The `next()` builtin function requires an iterator object, which is why a `TypeError` is raised.

If a class is to be used in the manner of an iterator, it needs a minimum of two methods:

- `__iter__()` Which is used to call `next()`.
- `next()`(Changed to `__next__` in Python 3) Which returns the next item from the iterator.

The [Python 2.7 documentations definition for `next()` can help confirm this](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next):

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `next()` method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

The most likely scenario, is that the `Reader` class does not implement the`__iter__()` method, which means the `next()` method cannot be called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a [Pcapy](https://www.coresecurity.com/corelabs-research/open-source-tools/pcapy) `Reader` object. While this object has a method named `next`, it is not an iterator and does not support iteration.

Ordinarily, this wouldn't matter, and the `next` built-in function would see the `next` method and call it, but `Reader` is written in C. A type written in C must provide a `tp_iternext` function in the C struct representing the type, not just a `next` method, to be recognized as an iterator, and this type sets `tp_iternext` to 0.

Comment: OK, Thank you. I think this is the real reason. Thank you. It very confused to me